# Function invoked from inside ngOnInit() is being called for every List Item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angular

I have a component that is a child component of it's parent.
The Parent component creates a list of child components using the `*ngFor`

Since the same child component is an Item of a list: `ngOnInit()` is called for every child component. I have an an observable which is being set for every child component which is inside the `ngOnInit()`.

When an even for the observable is triggered all the observables return the result instead of just that particular child component's observable for which the event has been triggered.

I want to add a handler that is able to distinguish which child component was triggered so that only that child component's observable returns a result.

```
<parent-component>
  <div *ngFor="let child of children">
    <child-component [child]="child"> </child-component>
<parent-component>
```

Child component's template:

```
<child-component>
  <redirect-overlay 
     [target] =>"speedbump+childIndex"
  </redirect-overlay>
  <button 
     data-toggle="modal"
     [attr.data-target]="#speedbump+childIndex"> 
</button>
<child-component>
```

The redirect overlay component set's a value in an observable. This observable is declared inside the `<child-component>`'s `ngOnInit()` function.

Whenever this observable receives a value it triggers all the child items and not just the child item for which the  was invoked.

For example: If there are 50 child components then the observable will be triggered for all 50 child components

The observable being set inside `<redirect-component>`:

```
    constructor(_overlayResponseObservableService: OverlayResponseObservableService){}

public navigateAway(event: any){
  this._overlayResponseObservableService.setReturnResponse("SOMEOBJECT");
}
```

Inside of `<child-component>`:

```
  constructor(_overlayResponseObservableService: 
              OverlayResponseObservableService){}
    ngOnInit(){
     this._overlayResponseObservableService.getReturnedResponse().subscribe(
     responseObj: any)=>{
    /* Do something here but this part is being called by every child
 item that is part of the list of the parent. This part is invoked for
 every child because this observable isn't able to differentiate for
 which child component 
it was called for, it is invoked for all children!
 I need to have the context of the child item that called the
 redirect-overlay */

}
    }
```

Comment: please add information about this event : where is it declared, where is it triggered : some code would help.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Please check, I have added my scenario

Comment: i still can't help without technical explanation about the event : please consider we need all the code involved to be able to help you.

Comment: what is the subject the observerbles are watching ? How does an observer know whether the event is for itself ?. Need more info

Comment: If your service is provided at `root`this will be the behaviour. It is a single instance. (A Singleton)

Comment: What is the responseObj here ? can you show what it contains

Comment: How about you move the subscription to the `ngOnInit` of your parent component and pass the value which you get from that subscription as another input to your child component ?

Comment: @ShijilNarayan responseObj is just a variable name for the subscription response. Also, I just tried your solution with the parent component, but the observable is called 21 times  which is equal to the number of children, same as it was being called in the child.

Comment: Once you move your subscription to your parent component, you wont be having any subscriptions in child ngOnInit method right ? Hence there should not be multiple subscriptions happening.

Comment: why not add a `@Input` in your children that was the "index", when iterate ise `*ngFor="let child of children;let i=index"` and check the "index"?